# how to get output of sql queries in Linux terminal?

Tags: mysql

I wrote sql queries on terminal. I am not able to find out the output of that query. Can anyone help me from where I will get the output .

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/353460/how-to-use-sql-in-terminal

Comment: could you give an example of a MYSQL command you used that didn't return anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can run queries on terminal like this:

```
mysql -u user -p -e 'Your SQL Query Here' <database-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in mysql terminal use:

```
mysql> \T /tmp/query.out
Logging to file 'query.out'
```

All queries output will be stored in **/tmp/query.out** file.